# Angular material 2 - input box not rendering properly as expected

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

I am using Angular material 2 for angular 4 application along with angular flex layout. Below is the simple form

```
<div fxLayoutGap="5px" fxLayout="column">
      <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Email Id" type="text" [(ngModel)]="emailId">
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Password" type="password" [(ngModel)]="password">
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
      </mat-form-field>
...
</div>
```

[image]

Sometimes it is showing base line but sometimes it is not behaving as expected. I tried on almost all browser but still facing same issue.

It is happing when you reduce/increase the size of your browser.

> It is not happening because of input type is password

Comment: can you edit this demo to show problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-material

Comment: I've been using angular material for a while (more than one year :) ), and never encountered this problem. Try updating to the latest version of angular material

Comment: @Deep3015
I suspect that this issue coming because of Angular Flex Layout. Component Behaviour is getting killed because of angular flex. I tried simple angular material it is working fine

Comment: @Ronnie use latest version https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-seed-r3d2yi?file=app/questionaire.component.ts

Comment: This seems like an Angular Material problem. Even when I remove flex layout, although all of the lines show up, there are differences in the thicknesses.

Comment: @Deep3015 Not sure but I am using latest versions.

Comment: @Ronnie you can compare above stackblitz dependencies with you project