# Angular Material Input Not Rendering Properly When Routed from Another Component

Tags: angular

When I route from one component to another the **Material Input**
doesn't render properly.

[image]

However if I just **refresh** the page everything renders perfectly. **PLEASE SEE EDIT BELOW**

[image]

The routes do not have any guards or resolvers.

A similar yet not identical issue was brought up here: [Angular material 2 - input box not rendering properly as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706438/angular-material-2-input-box-not-rendering-properly-as-expected)

however it seems like it was not resolved.

```
<div class="all">
   <div class="main">
      <h5 class="head"> Reserve Your Merch </h5>
      <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>
         <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
            <mat-card class="mainDiv">
              <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
                  <ng-template matStepLabel>Order Details</ng-template>
                  <p> <b> Order Details </b> </p>
                  <mat-form-field class="first">
                      <input matInput placeholder="First name" formControlName="name" required>
                  </mat-form-field>
                  <mat-form-field class="second">
                    <input matInput placeholder="Last name" formControlName="last" required>
                    <i matSuffix matTooltip="..." class="material-icons">
                        info
                   </i>
                  </mat-form-field>
                  <br>
                  <mat-form-field class="first">
                      <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" required>
                  </mat-form-field>
                  <mat-form-field class="second">
                      <input matInput placeholder="Phone Number" formControlName="phone" required>
                  </mat-form-field>

          <p> <b> Select Pickup Shows </b> </p>

          ....
     </form>
 </mat-card>
```

As you can see from the sample part of the code, there are no ngIf* constraints that would interfere with the rendering

I have also tried following a preloading strategy but it didn't make a difference

The issue persists in **all** components with matInput across the app, not just this component.

There are **no** errors in the console or terminal outputs

***EDIT: Found the cause of the issue, however no solution:***

I have dug deep into the material label and underline and discovered that the
styling from the previous component (the one navigated **from**) is effecting the 
current component. This shouldn't be happening as the components have no
parent-child relationship and are completely separate ...

[image]

Angular version: 7.2.4
Material version: 7.3.1

Full package.json

```
{
  "name": "guilty-gorilla-merch",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "front_end": "ng serve --open",
    "audit": "npm audit"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.19",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.1",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.3.2",
    "@ngu/carousel": "^1.4.8",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^6.1.1",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular2-click-outside": "^0.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng-sticky": "^0.1.5",
    "ng2-sticky-nav": "^0.1.0",
    "ng4-click-outside": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-drag-scroll": "^1.8.2",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.5",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.11",
    "@types/node": "^10.11.4",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

As much as this not a great solution, I did find a few work arounds.

Firstly, this is a known issue in Angular, however it looks like nothing has been done since May 2017.

The core of the problem goes down to **ViewEncapsulation.None** property leaking styling into other components in router environment. Read about the issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16670)

In this case, Material Form Fields, use this property. See source code [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/form-field/form-field.ts).
And it looks like the material team did not take the necessary precautions to prevent the styling from leaking.

As a temporary solution, you may enforce a different encapsulation type on your component => https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

however be aware that this may have unwanted side effects on your other styling, requiring to fix things up separately.

Unfortunately the other workaround (which I ended up choosing), is not to mix-up different themes and/or override any styling.

I have opened a separate ticket in the material repo: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/15274